# looking for a simple example program on how to login with google using OAuth 2.0

Tags: java, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I am new to OAuth, I am looking for a simple java example program on how to login with google using OAuth 2.0, I searched a lot but didn't find any appropriate solutions. Can anyone Please help me with this.

Comment: Google provides a lot of detailed sample projects, code and documentation. https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2

Answer (score 2):

I had a hard time with this myself. There are examples in different languages out there, but none of them really explain what's going on, and many rely on third-party libraries for the actual implementation. I do *not* recommend implementing a solution that uses any third-party libraries. Why? Because a lot of third-party libraries can easily fall behind in maintenance, security and bug fixes, and are sometimes abandoned altogether. I even caution against using Google's own libraries, because you are then still relying on Google to continue supporting that language. Not a risk worth taking when you're dealing with security and authentication.

A few years ago I dug in and figured out how to *actually* perform OAuth2 login and verification using nothing but standard libraries, complete with necessary validation to ensure the integrity of the data coming from Google. This is all in C#, but I tried to explain the code line-by-line as much as I could, so that should help you figure out how to do it in Java.

[This article covers the series (three parts) along with links to a bunch of documentation I found that helped immensely in understanding the OAuth2 process and how JWTs work.](http://www.abettergeek.com/web-development/the-big-picture-google-authentication-using-oauth2-and-asp-net-c/)

Google uses JWT - JavaScript Web Token - to return to your application the digitally-signed information you need to validate that the user is who they say they are. JWT is a standardized JSON-based format with three segments in a Base64-encoded string. The first two segments are straightforward and can be converted from Base64 into regular JSON. The third segment is a digital signature. [This documentation from the IETF explains, step-by-step, how the digital signature is created and how to use it to validate the data returned by Google.](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-jones-json-web-signature-04#page-14) Read it thoroughly so that you understand what you need to accomplish in your application.

I just did a quick search on Java's available libraries to support RSA PKCS#1 (this is what you need to validate the JWT signature against Google's public certificates) and am coming up empty-handed, but I'm also not a Java dev, so you might have an easier time finding what you need.

I want to stress something on this.

### If you can't figure out how to use RSA PKCS#1 to validate the digitally-signed data Google returns after the user authorizes your application, don't try to implement OAuth2 on your own.

There are serious security implications of allowing your application to authorize a user without properly validating their login information, and you definitely do not want to open yourself up to that possibility.

That being said, it's really not that hard once you figure out the digital signature part. The third part of my article series covers how this works pretty in-depth, so you should be able to figure out how to translate that into Java.

**In the most high-level view, here's what you want to achieve:**

1. Send the user to Google’s login service via URL
2. Process the GET data returned by Google
3. Request user details from Google via POST
4. Verify the returned, digitally-signed user data is valid

**The important bits you'll need are:**

- POST for submitting data to Google's OAuth2 service
- Base64 for decoding Google's JWT response into usable data
- Some way of locally caching Google's public certificates (they change about every 24 hours)
- X.509 for converting Google's public certificate (which is just the Base64 text representation of the cert) into an actual X.509 certificate object
- RSA PKCS#1 (**not** the same as RSA PKCS#11; they're two different standards and are not interchangeable) for validating the signed JWT against Google's public X509 certificate.

Please comment here (or on the blog) if you have questions about how it works, and I'll do my best to help. I have a background in both development and a little cryptography, so hopefully I can help you understand how everything works and why.

*Disclaimer: If it's against the rules to link to an article versus explaining here, I'll revise my post. OAuth2 is fairly involved, though, so trying to copypasta the entire code with explanation would be pretty arduous.*